# Check.Is tomcat running on linux

Tags: java

I have sample application written in java.And going to deploy on linux environment.But when i am going to run server using below command not sure is tomcat running or not.

I have tomcat server in linux environment.

```
[]# ./startup.sh
```

It is showing like this.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat7-myapp9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat7-myapp9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat7-myapp9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat7-myapp9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7- 
myapp9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Can you please suggest.What i am doing wrong.?

Comment: Did you try going to localhost:8080 and checking?

Comment: yes i tried but nothing happend.

Comment: Did you try checking log files under tomcat_directory/logs?

Comment: Yes checked. Its empty.